# Region of convergence (ROC) of Unilateral Laplace Transform

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, signal-processing

Is it necessary to define the region of convergence of Unilateral Laplace Transform if we know that the signal is causal in time domain?

Comment: $F(s) = \int_a^\infty f(t)e^{-st}dt$ with $a $ finite and $f$ locally integrable. If the integral converges for some $s_0$ then integration by parts gives $F(s+s_0) = \int_a^\infty (\int_a^t f(u)e^{-s_0 u}du) e^{-st}dt$, since$ |\int_a^t f(u)e^{-s_0 u}du| \le C$ it converges for every $\Re(s+s_0) > \Re(s_0)$ and uniformly for $\Re(s+s_0) > \Re(s_0)+\epsilon$.